# build command need to be executed inside a specific named directory "./package" from child folder or parent folder script terminal (cd) loop or regex

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, package.json, sveltekit, cd

how to write cd NAME_FOLDER and recursively search for it by name and then go to it if necessary (see below for more details).

the NAME_OF_FOLDER is unique so no worried about that.

---

but the challenging things are:

- that it needs to search from the PARENT to the CHILD,
- and if it didn't find it that way, search from CHILD to PARENT.

(or you can use any other logic if you think my logic is slow)

---

### example folder

here is an example image of my folder:

[image]

### possible scenarios

here are some scenarios:

- if I am inside

  - `./package` -> don't run `cd`
  - `./test` -> `cd ./package`
  - `./src` -> `cd ../ && cd ./package`
  - `./lib` -> `cd ../../ && cd ./package`

and so on for every deep folder structure

> **docs:**
>
>  `../` means go from child to parent
>
>  `./`  means go from parent to child

---

### why do I need it?

I am a javascript developer,

and I am using the sveltekit framework

to create a svelte package library.

and I need to publish that library to npm.

and this is ok.

but since I write a lot the same CLI codes.

 I am changing the `package.json`'s `scripts` object,

so I write only one time `npm run build` to run 6+ commands

```json
{
...
"build": "
svelte-kit sync 
&& svelte-package 
&& npm version patch
&& cd ./package # only this I need to solve this (the others are solved)
&& npm publish
&& git commit
"
}
```

> this is in one line, but for making you read it easily the code in multiple lines
>
> **here how it is in my code:**
> [image]

---

### what does the `build` command should do?

1. the command generates a `./package` folder always on the root of the folder

    (where we can find `package.json`, `.gitignore`, `./src`, etc...)
2. increase the number of versions automatically when we use the build command,

then... **TODO:**

3. do the script I need to access the `./package` folder from every folder I am in now. (like `cd ./package`)
4. `npm publish`

---

##### my os?

windows 11 (but using bash with vscode) or also powershell will be good but prefer bash

---

any other details, I will tell you. thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `find`? If the directory name is unique, you could to something like `cd "$(find / -name NAME_OF_FOLDER -type d)"`

Comment: @BenjaminW. no is unique everytime

Comment: @BenjaminW. the problem is to use `cd` correctly, basically if I am inside really nested child folder, I need to do a lot of `../`, so I thinked that maybe you can do a simple loop script that go from child to parent then get `./package` folder by doinf `cd`... I don't need to return nothing, just to make sure that I am inside the correct folder. so with npm publish I can share only the correct package. I hope it make sense

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, I tried to paste your code to the terminal it give me this error: `find: ‘/tmp/msdtadmin’: Permission denied` sorry but I don't know nothing about terminals (only basic stuff) maybe I don't get it but is there a way to do `cd ../` then check with `if` we are the root of folder (`./test` in this case) if no continue, if yes then write `cd ./package` since it is always on the root? (like while loop in javascript, but for terminals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing, I created this structure:

```
test/
    package/
    src/
        lib/
        routes/
```

Then I created that script:

```
#!/bin/bash

topdir="test"

while [[ $(basename "$(pwd)") != "$topdir"  ]]
do
    if [[ -d package ]]
    then
        cd package
        pwd
    else
        cd ..
        pwd
    fi
done

if [[ -d package ]]
then
    cd package
    pwd
fi
```

This script "climbs" the directories until it finds a "package" directory.  It the `cd` into it.

To use the script, you have to source it.  If you execute it, it will change directories while the script is running, but it will not affect your current terminal.

So, lets assume the script is `~/bin/cd_package.bash`
You would call it like this: `. ~/bin/cd_package.bash`

**Note** the `pwd` commands are just so you can follow what is going on and can be removed once you are convinced it works.